# How has the "Community" user got real rep?

Tags: bug

I had thought that the [Community user](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) didn't get rep. But it seems it does (even more oddly, only on Meta):

[image: Community user card]

Is that right? How does it happen?

[I never like shouting "Bug!" but that seems the most appropriate tag, unfortunately]

Comment: I think it's correct and happens on other sites too: [meta.stackoverflow: How much reputation does Community have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95590/how-much-reputation-does-community-have) I guess rep comes from edits?

Comment: @jfrej don't think it's supposed to; the rep referred to in that meta post has since disappeared.